# Issue with geometry when adding subdivision modifer

Tags: subdivision-surface, geometry

I modeled a teeth and when I add subdivision modifier I have this issue

[image]

I tried *Auto Smooth* but it doesn't solve, how to fix it and thanks in advance.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb1v0KLIx4YlIJYign6OFB4JW7V1WTyK/view?usp=sharing)

Some addition pictures
[image]
[image]

Comment: So is that crease supposed to be there at all?

Comment: no there is not crease it at -1.

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: this is link of blend. file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hb1v0KLIx4YlIJYign6OFB4JW7V1WTyK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you appear to have two parallel edges at the crease point, possibly duplicate vertices as well.  Try selecting all and merging by distance and also removing the extra edges.

Comment: there no extra edges or vertex. i have done merging by distance and there is 0 vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the following image (**1**), you have Normals pointing the wrong way. Blue facing out and red facing in. To fix this, Select All and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to Recalculate Normals. You can also go to Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> ). (**2**) Once Normals are recalculated to point in the same direction, the creases will be fixed.

Side tip : To visualize Normals like in the image. Check Face Orientation in the Viewport Overlays menu. (**3**)

### 1

[image]

### 2

[image]

### 3

[image]

Comment: thanks!!!!! it works :) .